# How much thread to choose during upload to cloud?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure-storage

I'm creating algorithm for efficiently upload page blobs

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(adjustmentBuffer, 0, bytesToWriteNow, false, false))
{
    _pageBlob.WritePages(memoryStream, Position, null, null, 
                     new BlobRequestOptions { ParallelOperationThreadCount = ?? });
}
```

How to choose `ParallelOperationThreadCount`and `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` ?

Comment: What library is a `PageBlob` from? Please update your question tags accordingly

Comment: It's a `CloudPageBlob`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, I would suggest starting with the Azure Storage Performance and Scalability Checklist to answer this question based on your application and performance requirements (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist). Please post back if this does not help. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I known about this checklist. But I was wondering why my upload speed is so slow. I just have `2.5 MB/sec` not 60MB/sec. Please, check also this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714362/why-upload-to-azure-blob-so-slow